# Cannot get simple weather feteching code to work

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm using the following code

```
try {
    const response = await fetch(endpoint);
    if(response.ok) {
        jsonResponse = await response.json();
        return jsonResponse;
    }
} catch(error) {
    console.log(error.message);
}
```

to fetch weather info from openweathermap.  When I run the program locally on my computer or using a local server with VSC I get a "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource." error caught.  When I input the URL (https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Madrid&appid=...)straight into the web browser it shows me the content without any issues.  I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong.  What am I missing? (the link is missing the api key for obvious reasons, but it's written correctly in the code)

Comment: What local web server are you using for development? Try and find one that can proxy URL patterns for you.

Comment: You're probably running into a Cross-origin Resource Sharing error. Proxying the URL will bounce the data from a non-browser request (CORS isn't required) to your own machine, lettings the browser think the resource is located on the same origin i.e. `localhost`. Are you able to set some sort of "allowed hosts" option in the openweathermap admin? You may also be able to allow `localhost` or `*`, which will allow your origin domain (where you're accessing the website) to access the resource.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try uploading it onto github sites see if it works there :)

Comment: That will be a pain to iterate locally though. Have a look at proxying your API urls for e.g. with https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server (there are many alternatives)

Comment: Alternatively, you can mock the requests when in development mode with https://mswjs.io/ and use https://marak.github.io/faker.js/ for the content.

Comment: Thanks for all the helpful comments.  Turned out to be something really silly.  The form's default behaviour was messing with the fetch function.  I added a preventDefault to the submit button and fixed!